# Mock methods of non default class exports in Jest Testing

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to mock a simple function in my service class.

// hello.controller.ts

```
@Get()
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    const result = await this.helloService.getHello();
    return result;
  }
```

// hello.service.ts

```
export class HelloService { 
    getHello(): string {
       return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

// mock.ts

```
export const mockHello = jest.fn((): string => {
  return 'Hello World!';
});

jest.mock('../src/hello/hello.service', () => ({
 get getHello() {
    return mockHello;
   },
 }));
```

When I tested the API Execution, the service function gets called instead of the mock function. How do I make my mockfunction to be called instead of the service function. The mock works only when I make my function static and use the following code in mock.ts.

```
HelloService.getHello = mockHello;
```

How to make the above scenario work without making the function static.